# How do I generate 100 randomly selected permutations for an array with 16 elements?

Tags: c++, arrays, permutation

I would like to generate 100 randomly selected permutations for an array with 16 elements.

The array = <1, 2, 3, . . . 16>

```
void printarray(int A[], int size)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << endl << A[i];
    cout << endl;
}

void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp;
    temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

void permutation(int *A, int start, int end)
{
    if(start == end)
    {
        printarray(A, end + 1);
        return;
    }
    int i;
    for(i = start; i <= end; i++)
    {
        swap((A + i), (A + start));
        permutation(A, start + 1, end);
        swap((A + i), (A + start));
    }
}
```

I used this to find all the permutations for an array with 4 elements, with the array = <1, 2, 3, 4>. However, I cannot use this to find 100 random permutations for the array with 16 elements.

Additionally, is there a program that I could use to find ALL permutations of the array A = <1, 2, 3, 4> AND only 100 random permutations of another array A = <1, 2, 3, ..., 16>?

Comment: [std::next_permutation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) will probably come in handy about now.

Comment: `std::shuffle` executed 100 times. Extremely tiny chance two of the permutations match but presumably 100 random permutations doesn't require distinct perms.

Comment: It’d probably be faster (and simpler) to just randomly select elements from the array until exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

This is a brute force approach, but each individual permutation can be stored in an instance of a sequence container allowing only unique values. And, all of the generated permutations can be stored in a set. Then your algorithm would be:

1. Create empty set of permutations.
2. Create empty permutation.
3. Push random values 1-16 into the permutation until its size reaches 16.
4. Insert permutation into the set.
5. If the size of the set is less than 100, go back to step (2).

---

**UPDATE:**

Here is an implementation that abuses `std::unordered_set` on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8262b54637e22812).

To do this properly you would need to implement your own container that combines properties of `std::vector` and `std::set`.

---

**UPDATE 2:**

Here is minimal implementation of `unique_sequence` container:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct unique_sequence
{
    auto size()  const { return v_.size();  }
    auto begin() const { return v_.begin(); }
    auto end()   const { return v_.end();   }

    void push_back(T e)
    {
        auto [ _, ins ] = s_.insert(e);
        if(ins) v_.push_back(std::move(e));
    }

    auto operator<(const unique_sequence<T>& rhs) const { return v_ < rhs.v_; }

private:
    std::vector<T> v_;
    std::set<T> s_;
};
```

You can use it to store individual permutations and the entire set of permutations.

Then, your algorithm becomes:

```cpp
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen{ rd() };
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist{ 1, 16 };

unique_sequence< unique_sequence<int> > perms;

while(perms.size() < 100)
{
    unique_sequence<int> perm;
    while(perm.size() < 16) perm.push_back(dist(gen));
    
    perms.push_back(std::move(perm));
}
```

And, here is complete implementation on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8a20d9e1398075d).

Answer (score 0):

Simple and fast way to generate permutations is to use `std::shuffle` and `std::next_permutation`. Shuffle uses the efficient [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) algorithm. Note that there are exactly 24 or 4! permutations in the {1,2,3,4} array.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <random>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void print(std::vector<T>& v)  // print vector of arrays
{
    for (const auto& a : v)
    {
        for (auto x : a)
            std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 4> a4{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }; // use std::iota for longer sequences
    std::array<int, 16> a16{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 };
    std::vector<std::array<int, 4>> a4_all;
    a4_all.push_back(a4);
    for (int i = 1; i < 2*3*4; i++) // there's 2*3*4=24 permuations
    {
        std::next_permutation(a4.begin(), a4.end());
        a4_all.push_back(a4);
    }
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g(rd());
    std::vector<std::array<int, 16>> vp100(100, a16);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        std::shuffle(vp100[i].begin(), vp100[i].end(), g); // shuffle is fastest
    print(a4_all);
    print(vp100);
}
```

[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/63bd6c556)

Comment: doug, how do you guarantee all permutations are unique?

Comment: @Super-intelligentShade The requirement was 100 randomly selected permutations. If they are randomly selected there is no guarantee one or more are not the same or the criteria would be unique permutations. There is even an infinitesimal probability all 100 are the same. Such is the nature of random. Still, the probability of one or more duplicates is approx 1/(16*15*14*13*12*11*10*9*8*7*6).

Comment: doug, you are correct. I've reread the question and the OP doesn't specify that they need to be unique.